# Capitalize and color the first letter after a period in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying figure out how to color the first word after the period.

I worked out capitalizing the first letter, but now I need it be colored. I preferred to be the first letter "red".

```
$(function () {
function capitalizeSentences(capText, capLock) {

    if (capLock == 1 || capLock == true) {
        capText = capText.toLowerCase();
    }

    capText = capText.replace(/\.\n/g, ".[-<br>-]. ");
    capText = capText.replace(/\.\s\n/g, ". [-<br>-]. ");
    var wordSplit = '. ';   

    var wordArray = capText.split(wordSplit);

    var numWords = wordArray.length;

    for (x = 0; x < numWords; x++) {
        wordArray[x] = wordArray[x].replace(wordArray[x].charAt(0), wordArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
        if (x == 0) {
            capText = wordArray[x] + ". ";
        } else if (x != numWords - 1) {
            capText = capText + wordArray[x] + ". ";
        } else if (x == numWords - 1) {
            capText = capText + wordArray[x];
        }
    }
    capText = capText.replace(/\[-<br>-\]\.\s/g, "\n");
    capText = capText.replace(/\si\s/g, " I ");
    return capText;
}
//Capitalize After Period
$("#capitalizeAfterPeriod").click(function () {
    var txt = $('textarea#generator').val();
    txt = capitalizeSentences(txt, true);
    $('textarea#generator').val(txt).addClass('period');
});
});
```

Comment: And the problem with the code is...?

Comment: I would like to color the first letter after the period.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add color to one letter in a textarea because textareas don't support rich text, if you want to use rich text you either need to use an element with the contenteditable attribute and then change the line to this:

```
    wordArray[x] = wordArray[x].replace(wordArray[x].charAt(0), '<span style="color:#color;">'+wordArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+'</span>');
```